# I have an issue sorting a structure on a VB homework assignment

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read in a number of wins and team names from text files and then I am trying to sort the structure via how many wins they have in descending order. However it will not let me order by `output.wins` and I am not sure why. I followed the examples the teacher has provided. In `let output.wins = output` it says that where the `.` is a `=` is expected. Could someone please point out what I have missed? I am not looking for an answer just a point in the right direction on what I have messed up.

```
Public Class frmScoccer

    Structure Team
        Dim name As String
        Dim wins As Integer
    End Structure

    Dim output() As Team 'this is going to be holder for the output data. 
    Private Sub frmScoccer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'this is going to be doing everything that needs to be done at load time. 
        Dim grabNames() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Names.txt") 'this is to pull the names from the text file. 
        Dim names() As String 'this is going to be the array that holds the names. 
        'this is going assigned the names to the array

        Dim grabWins() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Wins.txt") 'this is going to be used to grab the data on wins before it is assigned to the array. 
        Dim wins(,) 'this is going to hold wins and loses.

        nameAssignment(grabNames, output)
        winAssignment(grabWins, wins)

        countIf(wins, output) 'this is going to count the number of wins per team. 

    End Sub

    Sub countIf(wins, ByRef output)
        'this is going to bring the win counter up for a team if the value is true.

        For row As Integer = 0 To (wins.getupperbound(0))
            output.name(row) = 0
            For column As Integer = 0 To (wins.getupperbound(1))
                If wins(row, column) = "true" Then
                    output.wins += 1
                End If
            Next
        Next

    End Sub

    Sub nameAssignment(grabNames, ByRef output)
        'this is goning to be a way to get the names from the input array to the useable array. 
        Dim line, data() As String
        line = grabNames()
        data = line.Split(","c)
        For Each i As String In data
            output.name(i) = data(i)
        Next
    End Sub

    Sub winAssignment(grabWins(), ByRef wins(,))
        Dim line, data() As String
        For row As Integer = 0 To (grabWins.GetUpperBound(0))
            line = grabWins(row)
            data = line.Split(","c)
            For column As Integer = 0 To (grabWins.GetUpperBound(1))
                wins(row, column) = data(column)
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
        'this is going to display the output

        Dim query = From win In output
                    Let output.wins = output
                    Order By output Descending
                    Select win
        For Each win In query()
            dgvTeamWins.DataSource = query.Tolist
            dgvTeamWins.CurrentCell = Nothing

            dgvTeamWins.Columns("name").HeaderText = "Team"
            dgvTeamWins.Columns("wins").HeaderText = "Wins"
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `Dim query = From win In output Order By win.wins Descending`?

Comment: `I am not looking for an answer...` but that is what SO is all about!  its a Question and *Answer* site.  Its not for suggestions or general ideas which may or may not work depending on the implementation.

Comment: @Plutonix. Fair point.

Comment: @GSerg that fixed my issue. Thank you. Really should have seen that but I am still if-y on the concept of query's. I understand how they are set up but I do not understand why they work. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood how query's work. It was fixed by replacing

```
Dim query = From win In output
                    Let output.wins = output
                    Order By output Descending
```

with

```
Dim query = From win In output 
Order By win.wins Descending
```